# Cannot install OpenBLAS using "make" command

Tags: php, openblas

I'm trying to install OpenBLAS for Rindow Neural Network Library to build PHP machine learning environment.

I found several step-by-step introductions but they are all different and not specific enough. So I'm asking help.

What I've done was..

`download OpenBLAS file from git`,

`install Msys2`,
`install MinGW GCC package (using pacman -Fy mingw64 >> pacman -S mingw64-blabla..-gcc)`

`make system environment variable c:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

I checked the directory `msys64\mingw64` is filled with some files.

And I ran a command `make` on `c:\openblas` directory which is the location of binary file and I got ..

[image]

this. Any advise will be help. thx..

---

!! Problem solved

I finally solve this problem by following procedure.

- In `msys64` console, `pacman -S mingw64-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran`
- In `msys64` console, `pacman -S mingw64-w64-x86_64-cmake`
- Make `MinGW` folder in `OpenBlas` folder.
- Move OpenBLAS source files to MinGW folder.
- In `Powershell` console, run `cmake MinGW`

Comment: cannot find path,
avx512 is not a command, executable program, or batch file

Comment: I don't know about config.. actually, I don't understand the whole process of this but just following instructions and the instruction has no mention about config. Can you explain it  more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem by following procedure.

In msys64 console, pacman -S mingw64-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran

In msys64 console, pacman -S mingw64-w64-x86_64-cmake

Make MinGW folder in OpenBlas folder.

Move OpenBLAS source files to MinGW folder.

In Powershell console, run cmake MinGW